# Нужно изменить размер изображения на сервере php

Tags: php, изображения

Есть задача - менять размер изображения, чтобы оно было пропорциаонльно (квадратное). Только дело в том, что его нужно не кропить, а приращивать белые полосы по сторонам (скидываю пример).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть готовые решения, или варианты как это просто написать?

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием библиотеки [`GD`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php):

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng(__DIR__ . '/input.png');

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$limit = max([$width, $height]);

$leading = imagecreatetruecolor($limit, $limit);
$background = imagecolorallocate($leading, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($leading, 0, 0, $background);

if ($height >= $width) {

    $new_w = intval($limit * $width / $height);
    imagecopyresampled(
        $leading, $image, intval(($limit - $new_w) / 2),
        0, 0, 0, $new_w, $height, $width, $height
    );

} else {

    $new_h = intval($limit * $height / $width);
    imagecopyresampled(
        $leading, $image, 0, intval(($limit - $new_h) / 2), 0, 0,
        $limit, $new_h, $width, $height
    );

}

imagepng($leading, 'output.png');
```

Соответственно это лучше обернуть в какюу-либо функцию, чтобы при самой загрузке изображения видоизменять ее в нужный формат.

Comment: Это работает только с png изображениями. Как сделать, чтобы это работало и с JPG?

Comment: `imagecreatefrompng` => `imagecreatefromjpeg`и `imagepng` => `imagejpeg`

Comment: @user370473, примите решение (нажав зеленую галочку рядом), если оно верное